# Python error - ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, face-recognition, pca

I am trying to make face recognition by Principal component analysis (PCA) using python (matplotlib). I am trying to do it as described in this image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA

#Step1: put database images into a 3D array
filenames = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder/*.pgm')
filenames.sort()
img = [Image.open(fn).convert('L') for fn in filenames]
images = np.dstack([np.array(im) for im in img])

# Step2: create 2D flattened version of 3D input array
d1,d2,d3 = images.shape
b = np.zeros([d1,d2*d3])
for i in range(len(images)):
  b[i] = images[i].flatten()

#Step 3: database PCA
results = PCA(b.T)
x = results.Wt

#Step 4: input image
input_image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\1.pgm').convert('L')
input_image = np.array(input_image)
input_image = input_image.flatten()

#Step 5: input PCA
in_results = PCA(input_image.T)
y = in_results.Wt

#Step 6: get shortest distance
```

But I am getting an error from `in_results = PCA(input_image.T)` saying:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\Bachelor 2\New folder\new2.py", line 29, in <module>
    in_results = PCA(input_image.T)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 846, in __init__
    n, m = a.shape
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Anyone can help??

Comment: Can you post the actual traceback instead of just the error message?

Comment: @abarnert I've added the actual traceback instead of just the error message to the question

Comment: OK, I guessed right. The problem is that `n, m = a.shape`. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `PCA` constructor requires a 2D array, and assumes that you're going to pass it one. You can see that from the traceback:

```
in __init__ 
n, m = a.shape 
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Obviously if `a` is a 0D or 1D array, `a.shape` will not have two members, and therefore this will fail. You can try printing out `input_image.T.shape` yourself to see what it is.

But you have at least one problem with your code, possibly two.

First, even if you had a 2D array at some point, you do this:

```
input_image = input_image.flatten()
```

After that, of course, you've got a 1D array.

Second, I don't think you ever had a 2D array. This:

```
input_image = np.array(input_image)
```

… should create a "scalar" (0D) array with one object, based on what the `numpy` and `PIL` docs say. Testing it on various different setups, I seem to get a 0D array sometimes, a 2D array others, so maybe you're not having this problem—but if you aren't, you may get it as soon as you run on a different machine.

You probably wanted this:

```
input_image = np.asarray(input_image)
```

This will either give you a 2D array, or raise an exception. (Well, unless you accidentally open a multi-channel image, in which case it'll give you a 3D array, of course.)

Comment: when I added print to my code:
`#Step 4: input image
input_image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\1.pgm').convert('L')
input_image = np.array(input_image)
input_image = input_image.flatten()
print input_image` 
the output is 1D array

Comment: I tried it but no change. The change is when I remove `input_image = input_image.flatten()` (making `input_image` 2D array mot 1D). But I get another error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\Bachelor 2\New folder\new2.py", line 29, in <module>
    in_results = PCA(input_image.T)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 848, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('we assume data in a is organized with numrows>numcols')
RuntimeError: we assume data in a is organized with numrows>numcols`

Comment: It sounds like your new problem is that you already had the data organized properly in `input_image`, so `input_image.T` is wrong. If you can explain _why_ you added the flatten, transpose, etc., it might be easier to figure out what you _should_ be doing.